# Switching pages and displaying information on them PyQt6

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt

I am developing an application that will show a real-time graph in 1 window, and some information in the rest. So, I tried to write the program logic and make a layout. It turned out that I only display the graph (and for some reason it is very small) and the windows do not switch. Can you please help with this?
this is the xml layout translated into python.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1495, 788)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 131, 761))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=self.frame)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 111, 261))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 0, 1371, 31))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 30, 1371, 731))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);\n"
"background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(parent=self.frame_3)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 1361, 721))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(parent=self.page)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 0, 1181, 491))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 100, 831, 401))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.page_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 831, 401))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(80)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1495, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuw3rrewd = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent=self.menubar)
        self.menuw3rrewd.setObjectName("menuw3rrewd")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuw3rrewd.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 page"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 page"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 page"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 page"))
        self.menuw3rrewd.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "w3rrewd"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here is the code where I tried to implement it.

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untdwdfd.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.4.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
import pyqtgraph as pg
from untdwdfd import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_text1)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.show_text2)
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
        self.graphWidget.setXRange(0, 10, padding=0)
        self.graphWidget.setYRange(0, 10, padding=0)
        self.data = [0] * 10
        self.curve = self.graphWidget.plot(self.data, pen='b')
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_graph)
        self.is_button_pressed = False

    def plot_graph(self):
        self.is_button_pressed = not self.is_button_pressed
        if self.is_button_pressed:
            self.pushButton.setText("Stop Graph")
            self.timer.start()
        else:
            self.pushButton.setText("Start Graph")
            self.timer.stop()

    def update_graph(self):
        self.data.pop(0)
        self.data.append(pg.QtCore.QTime.currentTime().msec() / 1000)
        self.curve.setData(self.data)

    def show_text1(self):
        self.label_2.setText("it is empty here")

    def show_text2(self):
        self.label_3.setText("here is still empty")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit confusing, especially when you use indiscriminately "window" and "page". What should be switching, and how? And why are you creating the plot widget with the graphics view as parent? PlotWidget *already* is a graphics view.

Comment: I have an application with 3 windows, which I switch with the buttons on the left, and the information is displayed on the panel on the right. And about PlotWidget, I still don’t quite understand python and qt )

Comment: It's unclear to me too. See [ask]. What exactly is your problem? You mean other pages of the ```QStackedWidget``` do not show? Then, of course they do not. You didn't implement the switching logic. See [the reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html#details).